# Set magento blog post identifier to title automatically

Tags: magento, blogs

Is there anyway in Magento to set the blog post identifier to the blog post title automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your Block's `_prepareLayout()` method, write below line of code to set the Title of the page with your blog post ID.

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($id);
```